# Javascript - Datatables grid in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using Datatables grid in one of my application because it has a relatively exhaustive API for event dispatching and customization . But I am facing a problem now , the grid's height depends on the number of records to be displayed . How can I customize it so that it maintains the height even if records are deleted and continue to show empty cells from where the record was deleted ? Thanks .

Is there any better grid plugin than datatables which provides the features supported by datatables and where I would not face such problem .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add this into your table initialisation like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "sScrollY": "200px",
        "bPaginate": false, 
        "bScrollCollapse": false
    } );
} );
```

Where the sScrollY value will define the constant height of the table and bScrollCollapse set false will prevent the table from shrinking to fill empty cells.

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the CSS in order to achieve that. Other option is jqGrid.
http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html